# xpages add a html file into a facets

Tags: xpages

I'm using some `<xp:this.facets>` elements in my xpages.

I already imported a html file into my resources. I want to display this html file using this facets, but I'm not having any success.

They are numerous layouts using in the Xpage as I want to display a correct arrangement.

For a custom control, I did use something like this:

```
    <xc:layout>
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xc:view_all xp:key="facet_1"></xc:view_all> 

            </xp:this.facets>
   </xc:layout>
```

How can I do the same thing for my `test.html` ?

Comment: Do you want to paste the html markup inside the facet? or just insert the contents of the file (i.e. from a file resource)?

Comment: The contents of the file would be OK, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been explained by Sven Hasselbach:

http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=752

At the very basic level, you can dump contents of a file resource (from your Resources\Files inside the NSF database) into a computed text and place it as a facet.

```
<xc:layout>
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:text
            escape="false"
            xp:key="facet_1"
            id="computedField1">
              <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                   var url = "/test.html";
                   var data = facesContext.getExternalContext().
                       getResourceAsStream( url );
                   var txt = "";
                   while( data.available() ){
                       txt += @Char(data.read());
                   }
                   txt}]]>
               </xp:this.value>
        </xp:text>
    </xp:this.facets>
</xc:layout>
```

One quick note, during the JSF lifecycle, this code will run a number of times. So I recommend placing this into a SSJS lib and cache the contents once in a viewScope/applicationScope variable, depending on your case. Otherwise it will waste some memory and CPU during the loop.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I must wait several seconds until the content is displayed.

Comment: It depends on the size of the file. I'd use a Java bean for such caching.,